# Time complexity of algorithms

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, proof-assistants

I have some questions that I don't understand about time complexity.

1. Given that the worst case complexity of the algorithm $A$ is $O(f(n))$ and the best case
   complexity of $A$ is $Ω(g(n))$. It follows that $f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))$.
2. Given that the best case complexity of the algorithm $A$ is $O(f(n))$ and the worst case
   complexity of $A$ is $Ω(g(n))$. It follows that $f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))$.
3. Given that the average case complexity of the algorithm $A$ is $Θ(f(n))$ and the worst
   case complexity of A is $O(g(n))$. It follows that $f(n) ∈ O(g(n))$.

I will appreciate if you can help me understand those!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you! My question is how to prove or disprove statements like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and the last statements are correct, while the second one is *incorrect*.

### Statement 1

Denote by $T_{min}$ the actual running time of the algorithm $A$, in the best case, and $T_{max}$ in the worst case. By how we chose $T_{min}$ and $T_{max}$ it follows that $T_{min}\le T_{max}$.

From our assumptions, $T_{min}=\Omega(g(n))\implies T_{min}\ge c_1g(n)$. Also from our assumptions, $T_{max}=O(f(n))\implies T_{max}\le c_2f(n)$.

Combining them together we get:

$c_1f(n)\le T_{min} \le T_{max} \le c_2g(n)$, which means that $f(n)\le \frac{c_2}{c_1}g(n)\implies f(n)=O(g(n))$

### Statement 2

Consider the following algorithm:

```py
if lst[0] != 0:
    for x in lst:
        print(x)
```

And consider the inputs $I_1:=[0,1,2,3,...,n]$ and $I_2:=[1,2,3,...n+1]$.
Clearly, the algorithm takes $O(1)$ time with input $I_1$, but $\Omega(n)$ time with input $I_2$. Obvoiusly, $n\neq O(1)$ and thus the statement is incorrect.

### Statement 3

Repeat the proof of statement 1. Note that also $T_{avg}\le T_{max}$ and thus the proof still holds.

Comment: Wow -  thank you so much! This is very helpful, and I understand everything now! Thanks!